# Feed the Parallel.ForEach in time intervals

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

I am using simple method to return data to the `Parallel.ForEach`:

```
private IEnumerable<Recipient> GetRateLimitedResource()
    {
        IEnumerable<Recipien[]> chunks = _recipients.Chunk(100);
        foreach (var r in _recipients)
        {
            yield return r;
            //WHAT HERE
        }
    }
```

and then doing something like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(GetRateLimitedResource(), po, (Recipient recipient) =>
```

but how to set some kind of wait here, I mean I would like to chunk `_recipients` in the `GetRateLimitedResource()` and each chunk send to `Parallel.ForEach` with some kind of `Thread.Sleep(1000);`

Comment: Assuming you have a good reason for wanting to do this, I would suggest looking here: https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Batch.cs. But I'm interested to know why you want to do this. `Parallel.ForEach` has it's own rate-limiting options (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions(v=vs.110).aspx) which may be preferable.

Comment: @bornfromanegg do you think that using `TaskScheduler` form `Parallel.Options` would be better solution? I am sending emails in this `Parallel.ForEach` and going to have some break between groups of mail.

Comment: It depends if you are trying to reduce the load on the CPU or the mail server.

Comment: At this step I would like to reduce the load on the mail server.

Comment: Well yes, I think the batch solution would be better then.

Comment: I am already using smth similar to `Batch` and the question here is how to set some time break between buckets which are sent to the `Parallel.ForEach`

Comment: im confused as to what you are trying to achieve

Comment: `chunks` is never used in the original code. Why?

Comment: it is proof of concept code, now threre are two foreach loops and chunks are used in the first

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, you could just put your `Thread.Sleep` in your loop:

```
private IEnumerable<Recipient> GetRateLimitedResource()
{
    IEnumerable<Recipient[]> chunks = _recipients.Chunk(100);
    foreach (var r in _recipients)
    {
        yield return r;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

However, the above method will block it's own thread every time you sleep. I would move the 'delay' logic to the method which does the sending, and `await Task.Delay()` instead:

```
private async Task SendEmails()
{
    foreach (var chunk in _recipients.Chunk(100))
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(chunk, po, recipient => ... // your send method here            
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

There is a potential further optimisation you could make, however. You have not provided the code that actually sends the emails, but sending an email is essentially an asynchronous operation, and would benefit from being written as such. If it were, then the emails could be sent asynchronously rather than in parallel. The code for that would look something like this:

```
private async Task SendEmails()
{
    foreach (var chunk in _recipients.Chunk(100))
    {
        var sendTasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (var recipient in chunk)
        {
            sendTasks.Add(SendEmail(recipient)); // your SendEmail method here
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(sendTasks);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}

private async Task SendEmail(string recipient)
{
    // your send email logic here
}
```